# Fail to deploy a website with dummy backend

Tags: html, node.js, heroku, frontend, backend

I've created a project consisting only HTML files and I want to deploy this on Heroku. So I've created a dummy backend to deploy on Heroku but when I run this on localhost then it shows me an error that **no such file or directory**

error pic:

[image]

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'project.html'));
});

// add other routes below
app.get('/Vaccine2', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'Vaccine2.html'));
});

app.get('/hospital', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'hospital.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Share the code as text, instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash `\` to the file names.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '\project.html'));
});

// add other routes below
app.get('/Vaccine2', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '\Vaccine2.html'));
});

app.get('/hospital', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '\hospital.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First delete a branch in Git**

```
rm -rf .git
```

after then create an src directory on the project

**and change your code**

this:

```
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
```

to this:

```
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/src')));
```

go your package.json file and add your node.js version like:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "14.x"
 }
```

and try deploy your website again

```
git add .
git commit -m "Added a Procfile."
heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
...
heroku create
Creating arcane-lowlands-8408... done, stack is cedar
http://arcane-lowlands-8408.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:arcane- 
lowlands-8408.git
Git remote heroku added
git push heroku main
...
-----> Node.js app detected
...
-----> Launching... done
   http://arcane-lowlands-8408.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

**Some Recorses you can check it out:**

[Heroku hosting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

First think first be sure the you type all comments correctly in heroku.
Feel free to send a message back if you will figure it out or not.